# Need help to build a mini project based on Automated Theorem Proving using C language

Tags: automation, theorem-proving

I am a fourth year B.Tech student of  Computer Science and Engineering and our team is working on a mini project on Automated Theorem Proving. Our main aim is to find out whether a geometrical theorem is valid or not, based on the axioms and inputs that we feed to the prover program. We want to design our code using C programming language, but the initial problem is that we can't find a way how to represent the axioms. Is there any way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Have you tried representing the axioms in mathematical way? Or perhaps try using the Laws of Logic.